# Integrated Windows Authentication not working for MVC .NET web app on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, windows-authentication

I'm working on a .NET MVC web app, and I'm using Windows authentication. My IE has "Integrated Windows Authentication" enabled, and it works when I navigate to other sites hosted on the same IIS server (a.k.a I am not prompted for login). However when I go to this one page and call an API method, `base.isAuthorized(actionContext)` evaluates to `false` in the C# code, resulting in me being shown the login dialog. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I thought Windows Authentication would authenticate me right when I enter the webpage... why am I still prompted for credentials?

Answer (score 0):

Authentication settings can be different for each web site on the server.  Check your IIS settings for this particular web site.  Make sure that Windows Authentication is enabled, and that Anonymous Authentication is *disabled*.

Comment: Those settings are right. Windows Authentication should authenticate the user right when they enter the page correct? Then I'm checking `if base.isAuthorized(actionContext)` when the user clicks something, and it evaluates to `false`, hence why I'm getting prompted for credentials again..